# Is there an api to the Mac-OS where I can disable screen dim from an application (like python) and when I am ready I can enable it again?

Tags: mac, screen, python

I have an application to run a slideshow on the mac. I would like to disable screen dimming when I start the slideshow, and enable it again when I stop the slideshow... Therefore I need an api into the MAC to do so. Is anybody aware of such api?  ( I am aware of caffine - but that disables this for the whole application...I only want when I have selected screenshow.)

Comment: Invoke `caffeinate` as a subprocess before starting the screen show and kill it afterwards?